# Как получить список через 2 связанных модели? rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Имеем три модели. `User`, `Pet`, `City`.

```
# user.rb   
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets
  belongs_to :city
end

# pet.rb
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

# city.rb
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

Как получить список животных `Pet`, юзеры которых живут в определенном `City`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить связь `has_many :pets, through: :users` в модель `City`.
Тогда у объекта класса `City` появится метод `pets`, который будет возвращать животных, владельцы которых из этого города.

Comment: спасибо, работает. только through: :users

Comment: @AlexIvanov поправил